# Gsutil setting All Authenticated Users permission

Tags: google-app-engine, gsutil

My google app engine application refers images in a storage bucket. I uploaded them using the Developer Console. Right now when I load my application and error occurs.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageException' with message 'Access denied to image.' in ...
```

I can fix this error by changing the `"All Authenticated Users"` for each object using the Developer Console. Practically this is a time consuming job since I have lot of images in my bucket.

Is there a way to set `"All authenticated user"` permission for **all the objects** in my storage bucket through gsutil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you can use something like this:

```
gsutil -m acl ch -R -g AllAuth:R gs://my-bucket/
```

For more information : [DOCUMENTATION](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl)

Comment: Thanks Radia. This seems the solution. However this made "All Authenticated Users" to "Reader" . How can I make it to "Owner" ?

Comment: AllAuth:FC instead of AllAuth:R. this gives full control to users

Comment: Yap, spot on. Thanks dude!